# Application Exit on Synthesizer.Speak - System.Speech.dll - Non Microsoft Voices

Tags: c#, speech

I have an issue in that my understanding of the reason for the issue is alluding me and not so much the process to circumvent the issue. I wonder if someone can further explain why I am getting this issue?

I populate a ComboBox with the Local Computer's Installed Voices:

```
private void getSystemVoices()
{
foreach (InstalledVoice voiceName in synthesizer.GetInstalledVoices())
{
this.voiceComboBox.Items.Add(voiceName.VoiceInfo.Name);
}
}
```

My Application is running under x86 CPU so all Installed Voices are populated in this ComboBox. I have some Acapela Voices Installed, I believe they are SAPI 5.1 compliant. Lucy, Heather and Ryan.

I am testing this code to use the Voices:

```
// Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer...
SpeechSynthesizer synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer();

// Config the audio output... 
synthesizer.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

// Initialize a new instance of the PromptBuilder...
PromptBuilder promptBuilder = new PromptBuilder();

// Config SSML...
promptBuilder.AppendSsmlMarkup("<voice xml:lang=\"en-AU\">");
promptBuilder.StartVoice(this.voiceComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
promptBuilder.AppendText("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
promptBuilder.EndVoice();
promptBuilder.AppendSsmlMarkup("</voice>");

// Speak the prompt...
synthesizer.Speak(promptBuilder);
```

My Problem:
If I have any of the Voices selected other than "Microsoft Anna", my Application Exits. Even if I use Try/Catch statements. I get no error and no debug info to say an error has occurred. This issue does not occur if I don't change the default Voice.

In my understanding Microsoft Speech API was to be backward compatible?

[Microsoft Speech](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145021%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I am using .net4.5, referenced System.Speech.dll V4.0.0.0.

Is anyone able to explain this behaviour?

[**EDIT**]
Please Note: The code for SPVoice works:

```
using SpeechLib;

// SAPI 5.1 Speech Config...
SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();
voice.Rate = speechRate.Value;
voice.Volume = speechVolume.Value;
voice.Voice = voice.GetVoices("", "").Item(voiceComboBox.SelectedIndex);
voice.Speak(readerTextBox.Text, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);
```

Its only with the Microsoft SpeechSynthesizer that the problem occurs.

Comment: Exceptions that occur in unmanaged threads cannot be seen by the CLR.  You'll definitely see something in the Output window.  You need support from the voice vendor to get somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Hans, yes I also suspected some sort of broad support issue with the Microsoft Code and the other Installed Voices. Both Ivona and Acapela have the same issue, so I suspect it is not in the voices so much but in the Microsoft Base Code in Speech.dll

Comment: this might be a useful link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723614(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi Frank, please see above: SpVoice Voice property (SAPI 5.3) this works. The problem is in the System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer Class, not in the SPVoice Class

Answer (score 0):

When your .Net application crashes like that, you will usually see an event in the computers application eventlog. You can find the eventlog by doing the following (Windows 7):

- Click start
- Right-click `computer` or `my computer`
- In the left treeview, Expand `Event Viewer`
- Expand `Windows Logs`
- Click on `Application`

You should see an error icon in the log, with details about the crash.

If you want to crash an application preventing any try-catch blocks from catching an exception, you can do so intentionally by calling `Environment.FailFast();` It is not recommended or to do this normally (except for a few common cases where memory is corrupt or tampering is detected). It will have the same effect as some native code's misbehavior, the Mushroomed-SuperMario among exception throwers :-). Though this does not directly answer your question, the way it blasts through your catches indicates that it is probably an error of similar order (corrupt memory, or the voice detects unlicensed use or such).

Comment: Hi Louis, understand what you're saying and yes I have already done the typical checking of the Event Logs under the application Tab, also System tab to see if any more information has been logged. No Error is logged! All my voices are licenced and work in other applications. Using Environment.FailFast does not work in this situation. If you have tested this code please post your code example. Unfortunately this information does not help solve this issue.

Comment: It is extremely rare for an application to crash like you describe without any event-log message being logged (it should be logged by the OS, not by the .Net application). I suspect that it is not crashing after all. Does a breakpoint behind the catch get hit? I assume you are on Windows forms, so if you override `OnClosing` and `OnClosed` on the main form and put breakpoints in there, do they get hit? If so, examine the stack-trace to see where the close command was coming from.

Comment: I have used Computers for some 30 Years, I agree it is not very common to see events not logged. However, it does happen. Please feel free to test the Code I have provided above. I believe, like Hans has pointed out, the problem here is this is Un-Managed Code. Not Marshalled in Application. Microsoft Speech.dll is problematic under certain conditions. It appears that it is not fully backward compatible.

Comment: I did test your code but was lacking the custom voices which don't seem to be free. Have you also looked into the trace? It will log to your debug output in Visual Studio by default, but a tool like [SysInternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) would also show them. Wow, you've been using computers for a long time! Remember the old [Microsoft Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Agent) speech API? And how about [Sam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#SAM) on the C64?... Never mind, thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Yes, Old school, Vic 20, ZX Spectrum, all the fun of loading Games from 5 and 1/2 inch Floppy's or old tape drives. Cant remember Sam on the Commodore C 64 though? Yes, no errors in Output windows as such, one message that looks a bit ominous. will try to get it ant post, I felt it was not related.